# Concatenating text of child nodes into a single column

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008, xpath, xquery

I'm working with an API that returns property information.  Some of the textual information is stored across child nodes and I'd like to concatenate it into a single string (VARCHAR).

My process is that I obtain the xml through a webservice, then pass this through to a proc which extracts the xml values and inserts them into a view, this is a snippet of the xml that I'm getting back:

```
<properties>
    <property propertyid="1234">
        <bullets>
            <bullet>nice garden</bullet>
            <bullet>it smells a bit</bullet>
            <bullet>body under the patio</bullet>
        </bullets>
    </property>
    ...
</properties>
```

This is a glimpse into how the xml is being queried to extract values from it:

```
INSERT        
INTO          VProperty
(             PropertyId,
              Description
)
SELECT        P.value('@propertyid', 'INT'),
              NULL -- extract all the bullet text values into a single string
FROM          @xml.nodes('/properties/property')
```

In this example, I'd like to be able to extract the information from the xml so it ends up like this:

```
PropertyId    Description
1234          'nice garden\r\nit smells a bit\r\nbody under the patio
```

Is this going to be possible in pure sql/xml or am I going to need to perform some pre-processing on the xml before I enter SQL land?

Any help greatly appreciated (as always).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
DECLARE @XML XML = 
('<properties>
    <property propertyid="1234">
        <bullets>
            <bullet>nice garden</bullet>
            <bullet>it smells a bit</bullet>
            <bullet>body under the patio</bullet>
        </bullets>
    </property>
    <property propertyid="2345">
        <bullets>
            <bullet>bullet 2345_1</bullet>
            <bullet>bullet 2345_2</bullet>
            <bullet>bullet 2345_3</bullet>
        </bullets>
    </property>
</properties>');

SELECT  X.node.value('@propertyid', 'INT'),
        STUFF((SELECT '\r\n' + B.bullet.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
               FROM   X.node.nodes('./bullets/bullet') B ( bullet )
               FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),
              1, 4, '') AS Description
FROM    @xml.nodes('/properties/property') X ( node );
```

Comment: Boom.  I came across something similar when looking for a solution but could never get it working - this works perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this XQuery (not sure if SQL Server 2008's dialect of XQuery is fully compatible with it):**

```
for $pr in /*/property,
    $id in $pr/@propertyid,
    $desc in string-join($pr/*/*, '&#xD;&#xA;')
  return
     (<PropertyId>{string($id)}</PropertyId>,
     <Description>{$desc}</Description>)
```

**With Saxon and XQSharp (XmlPrime) the result of applying this query on the provided XML document**:

```
<properties>
    <property propertyid="1234">
        <bullets>
            <bullet>nice garden</bullet>
            <bullet>it smells a bit</bullet>
            <bullet>body under the patio</bullet>
        </bullets>
    </property>
    ...
</properties>
```

**is**:

```
<PropertyId>1234</PropertyId>
<Description>nice garden&#xD;
it smells a bit&#xD;
body under the patio</Description>
```

Comment: This looks very elegant but I haven't been able to shoe-horn it into my example - possibly a compatibility issue like you mentioned. Thanks for your time either way.

Comment: @PhilCooper, Somebody who knows SQL Server XQuery can help. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @XML XML
SET @XML = 
'<properties>
  <property propertyid="1234">
    <bullets>
      <bullet>nice garden</bullet>
      <bullet>it smells a bit</bullet>
      <bullet>body under the patio</bullet>
    </bullets>
  </property>
  <property propertyid="2345">
    <bullets>
      <bullet>bullet 2345_1</bullet>
      <bullet>bullet 2345_2</bullet>
      <bullet>bullet 2345_3</bullet>
    </bullets>
  </property>
</properties>'

SET @XML = @XML.query('
    for $prop in /properties/property
    return
    <property propertyid="{string($prop/@propertyid)}">
        <description>
        {
            for $bullet in $prop/bullets[1]/bullet
            return
                if ($bullet is $prop/bullets[1]/bullet[1] and $bullet << $prop/bullets[1]/bullet[last()])
                then concat(string($bullet), "\r\n")
                else
                    if ($bullet is $prop/bullets[1]/bullet[last()])
                    then string($bullet)
                    else concat(string($bullet), "\r\n")
        }    
        </description>
    </property>
')

SELECT
Tab.ColXML.value('@propertyid', 'INTEGER') AS PropertyId,
Tab.ColXML.value('description[1]', 'NVARCHAR(128)') AS Description
FROM @XML.nodes('//property') AS Tab(ColXML)
```

As there is no let clause in MS SQL server 2005, I have to find a work around.

In the expression in the query() method, I use 2 nested "loop-like" for clauses to select needed elements.
The first [for clause] to build the [property] elements. The 2nd [for clause] to build the [description] elements, the child element of the [property], from the list of [bullet] elements.

The [description] will get the value from the sequence built from the list of [bullet] elements like the following way:

The first but not last [bullet] will be appended with "\r\n".

The not first and not last [bullet] will also be appended with "\r\n".

We keep other [bullet] intact.

We concatenate all the strings built for each  to make value for the relevant [description].